# Saving a number as 01 instead of 1 in oracle database

Tags: oracle, types, oracle11g, numbers

I made this procedure to put all times of the day (24 hour clock) in a table.

```
create or replace
procedure fill_time as

l_hour number(2) :=0;
l_minute number(2):=0;
l_hourminute varchar2(5);

BEGIN


while l_hour<=23 loop
  while l_minute<=59 loop
l_hourminute :=to_char(l_hour)||':'||to_char(l_minute);
 insert into times(hour,minute, hourminute) values(l_hour, l_minute,l_hourminute);
l_minute:=l_minute+1;
 END LOOP; 
l_minute:=0;
l_hour:=l_hour+1;
END LOOP;
 END;
```

now it works fine and all but the times are stored as 0:0 for instance. how can I make sure it is stored as 00:00 instead?

Comment: Sounds to me like you're mixing up your data (which should store 0) with your presentation (which should display 00). You probably don't want your DB to store "00"

Comment: From **database design** point of view, it is a bad idea to store **datetime** as separate elements in a string format. A **DATE** has both the **date and time portions** till seconds precision. All you need is extract the required elements for **datetime arithmetic**.

Comment: I guess It's a design flaw... there is a table called measurements which is filled using an external table in a .csv file. Dates and times are in a seperate table and put in as ID's in the measurment tables. I can't see any valid reason for this method thoug since you can simply store the date and the time directly from the .scv file into the measurments table I guess..

It's just that the relational model isn't fully designed by myself. I would have dropped the date and times table and just inserted those directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
l_hourminute :=to_char(l_hour)||':'||to_char(l_minute);
```

To:

```
l_hourminute :=TRIM(to_char(l_hour, '09'))||':'||TRIM(to_char(l_minute, '09'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Quite apart from the bizarre need to insert the hours from 00:00 to 23:59 into a table (why?! Please explain more about your requirement, I'm very curious about it!), you don't need to do this as a procedure - you can easily do it in a single insert statement:

```
insert into times (hour,minute, hourminute)
select to_char(trunc(sysdate) + (level - 1)/(24*60), 'hh24') hr,
       to_char(trunc(sysdate) + (level - 1)/(24*60), 'mi') min,
       to_char(trunc(sysdate) + (level - 1)/(24*60), 'hh24:mi') hourminute
from   dual
connect by level <= 24*60;
```

But as others have said, you typically wouldn't want to store your times separately to your date information.

Comment: I asked my supervisor today. He said it's because of datawarehousing principles.